# Why is Iterable not explicitly defined as a functional interface?

Tags: java, interface, java-8, functional-interface

As of Java 9, `Iterable` is defined as the following (without documentation, for brevity):

```
public interface Iterable<T> {
    Iterator<T> iterator();

    default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(action);
        for (T t : this) {
            action.accept(t);
        }
    }

    default Spliterator<T> spliterator() {
        return Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator(), 0);
    }
}
```

As we can see, this interface only contains one abstract method.  Because one or more of the methods in this interface utilize the `default` keyword, this interface must have been edited since the release of Java 8 (the documentation defines `@since 1.8`, but was not included in this question).

For those reasons, why is `Iterable` not defined with the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation?

Comment: It seems to me having one abstract method is a necessary but not sufficient requirement for annotation with `@FunctionalInterface`. Or can you think of a good use case where `forEach` would serve in a lambda expression (as opposed to receiving a lambda expression as argument)?

Comment: This looks exactly like the Java 8 release version. Why do you think it “must have been edited since the release of Java 8”?

Comment: @Holger I meant to say that it was edited with Java 8

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. You may replace “since” with “for” or “with”…